# two dimensional points under straight line

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I have huge set of points `(x,y)` for example `(15, 176) (65, 97) (72, 43) (102, 6) (191, 189) (90, 163) (44, 168) (39, 47) (123, 37)` I need to find all the points which fits under `(0,0) to (max-x, max-y)`. In this example these points will be `(0,0 ) and (191,189)` , so I draw all the points, I need to find all the points which are under the line which is from `(0,0) to (191,189)`  Is there any standard algorithm to do this.

Comment: Nothing much yet, I inserted all the points in a vector and then thought sorting by x and by y would help, but that does not, also thought about k-d tree, but no luck yet.

Comment: Please can you clarify more precisely what you mean by 'fits under' here? Paul and I interpreted it differently, so it seems to be a bit vague.

Comment: Sorting by x is a bit of an overkill if you just wnat to discard those points, that have a too big x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A point (x, y) is under the line from (0, 0) to (X, Y) if y * X < Y * x.

Comment: And x<=X if you use a strict definition of "under"

Comment: @EugenRieck - Absolutely correct, but since X is defined as max-x, this condition is automatically satisfied for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 2):

(I'm assuming that by 'fits under' you mean 'under' as in 'overlaid by'.)

Well one approach would be to determine the points on the line using e.g. Bresenham's line algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) and then use `std::set_intersection` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_intersection/) to find which points are both in the line and also in the original set of points you had.

Answer (score 2):

Being under the line segment (0,0)->(191,189) is equal to

- having x<=191
- having y < x*(const 189/191)

Sow these are the 2 conditions you would have to check on each point. 
You have costs of 1 integer comparison, 2 int to float casts, 1 float multiplication, 1 float comparison per point

Comment: BTW: Can someone tell me, how to use the less-than sign in a UL on Stackoverflow?

Comment: Use &lt; for less-than, as you would in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

For any line y=mx+c where m is the slope and c is the y intercept

use the values
a = y-mx-c for x=0,y=0
b = y-mx-c for the general point

if a and b have the same sign means the points are on the same side
otherwise they are on the opposite side of the line

I have kept (0,0) for finding a so that one can compare the general point's position w.r.t. origin. You could input any other point in it too..

Hope that completely helps your problem